# DocumentView does not contain definition for TabDocumentLoaded and has no extension method TabDocumentLoaded accepting first arg of type DocumentView

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pdftron

In my xamarin.forms project I am working with PDFTrons libraries. Among them, one is **PDFTron.Android.Tools** with version 7.0.3

But today I have updated that package to 8.0.0 and I am facing this error

`CS1061 'DocumentView' does not contain a definition for 'TabDocumentLoaded' and no accessible extension method 'TabDocumentLoaded' accepting a first argument of type 'DocumentView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I am not able to use the **TabDocumentLoaded()** method

please help me with this

thank you in advance !!!

Comment: We are looking into this issue. Could you contact us at https://pdftron.freshdesk.com/a/tickets/17927? Thanks!

Comment: I believe we've identified the problem and this should be fixed in 8.0.1 update that is happening in the next few days. Thanks!

Comment: hi @ShirleyG
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in 8.0.1 release of PDFTron Xamarin SDK.